# Replace values in dictionary with values from constants

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary

I'm working with Django and I have a class to define some constants (I use this in my models)

```
class ArticleStatus:

  OPEN = 'open'
  CLOSED = 'closed'
  BLOCKED = 'blocked'

  CHOICES = (
    (OPEN, 'Open'),
    (CLOSED, 'Closed'),
    (BLOCKED, 'Blocked')  
  )
```

In my view I have a queryset which gives me this result:

```
context['total'] = [
  {'status': 'open', 'total': 102},
  {'status': 'closed', 'total': 150},
  {'status': 'blocked', 'total': 24}
]
```

My goal is to convert the status values to the more readable values from the constants. I did this with the following code

```
for i in range(0, len(context['total'])):
  status = context['total'][i]['status']
  for status_const in ArticleStatus.CHOICES:
    if status == status_const[0]:
      context['total'][i]['status'] = status_const[1]
```

And the converted result is:

```
context['total'] = [
  {'status': 'Open', 'total': 102},
  {'status': 'Closed', 'total': 150},
  {'status': 'Blocked', 'total': 24}
]
```

[Working example](https://repl.it/@sascha95/NegligibleFirmResources)

However, my code does not look very efficient and I wanted to ask if anyone has a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use a `for` loop to iterate your list and use a pre-calculated dictionary mapping:

```
choice_map = dict(ArticleStatus.CHOICES)

for item in context['total']:
    item['status'] = choice_map[item['status']]

print(context)

{'total': [{'status': 'Open', 'total': 102},
           {'status': 'Closed', 'total': 150},
           {'status': 'Blocked', 'total': 24}]}
```

Comment: Wow perfect, that looks a lot cleaner. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest I could come up with:

```
CHOICES = {OPEN: 'Open',
           CLOSED: 'Closed',
           BLOCKED: 'Blocked'}  

print([{'status': ArticleStatus.CHOICES[x['status']],
        'total': x['total']} for x in context['total']])
```

You could cut it down more by doing an in-place mutation but I always appreciate a clear functional style as a starting point.